# How to mock a Jupyter notebook environment in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, jupyter-notebook, pytest

I'm writing a Python function that displays images differently based on the execution environment: directly in a Jupyter notebook if detected, or otherwise, by opening the image in the default system viewer. I plan to write `pytest` tests to verify both behaviors, but I'm unsure how to mock the presence of a Jupyter notebook environment.

Here's the simplified function:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

def display_image(image_bytes):
    try:
        # Attempt to display in a Jupyter notebook
        display(Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)))
    except NameError:
        # Fallback to opening in the default image viewer
        Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)).show()
```

How do I write a test using `pytest` to simulate running within a Jupyter notebook environment and also outside of it, to ensure `display_image` functions correctly in both cases?